# Cannot Invoke Method with @onclick in Blazor Button Component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, onclick, blazor

I've been working on a Blazor project and encountered an issue trying to call a method using `@onclick` in a Button component. Despite several attempts and modifications, the button does not seem to trigger the method as expected. Below is the code snippet that I'm currently working with:

```html
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<Button Clicked="@OpenTwitterInNewTab" Class="iconButton" Color="Color.Primary" Outline>
    <Icon Name="@("fab fa-twitter")" />
</Button>
```

And the corresponding C# method in my `@code` block:

```cs
@code {
    private async Task OpenTwitterInNewTab()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Navigating to Twitter...");
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", "Navigating to Twitter...");

        var twitterUrl = $"https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text={Uri.EscapeDataString(VideoContent.Title)}&url={Uri.EscapeDataString(NavigationManager.Uri)}";
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("open", twitterUrl, "_blank");
    }
}
```

For some reason, neither the web console nor the server console prints the log statements, indicating that the method is not being called at all. I've checked for any possible typos or syntax errors but couldn't find any. It seems like the button click is not triggering the method even though I use the same syntax as demonstrated in the [Blazorise Documentation](https://blazorise.com/docs/components/button) for Clicked events for their Button component, which I am utilizing here.

Could anyone please help me figure out what might be going wrong here? Is there something I'm missing or overlooking in the Blazor syntax or component usage?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Either show the `Button` component implementation or tell us the library it comes from. Looks like it's from `Blazorise` so you have to use `Clicked="OpenTwitterInNewTab"`. [documentation](https://blazorise.com/docs/components/button).

Comment: `onclick=` expexts a JS function, at best.  You need `@onclick=` or `Clicked=` or something.

Comment: Apologies for the oversight; yes, you are correct. The @onclick attribute is indeed for a C# method. I've also tried using Clicked, just as the documentation suggests, but unfortunately, it's still not working. :(

Comment: State your application type (the Interactivity options) and include the top lines of your page.

Comment: If even @onclick="OpenTwitterInNewTab" doesn't work, you may need render modes in .net 8 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: @QiangFu thank you this was the problem the whole time, after I activated serverside rendering everything worked as intended.